# Outer join a subquery of the most popular occurrence of a plant species

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
MySQL 5.5.43
```

I'm working on a database of 7,200 cannabis strains and need to display a list of strains along with the most popular claimed species by their breeders.

The subject is quite confusing, so here's a few facts that will help you understand where my confusion lies:

- Each cannabis strain is one of the following species; Indica, Sativa
  or Ruderalis, or it could be a cross of all three.
- Popular strains may have up to 30 different breeders producing seeds of this strain.
- Each breeder of this one strain may have slightly different crosses/genetics and report different species. For example: Breeder1 claims StrainX is 100% Indica and Breeder2 claims StrainX is Mostly Indica (maybe 90% Indica and 10% Sativa). Apparently the effects of a Sativa plant are uplifting and Indica a bit depressing, so it's quite important to log the slight differences in each breed for medicinal purposes.

**EXAMPLE STRAIN:**

For one very popular strain called White Widow, this is a result set I produced. It has 29 different breeders with each breeder claiming different species. As you can see in the results, the most popular species for this strain is Indica/Sativa (an equal hybrid).

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  b.id AS breederID,
  b.breederName AS breederName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.species ORDER BY sp.species ASC SEPARATOR '/') AS species
FROM strains AS s
LEFT JOIN strainBreedersDir AS sbd ON s.id = sbd.strainID
LEFT JOIN breeders AS b ON sbd.breederID = b.id
LEFT JOIN strainBreederSpeciesDir AS sbsd ON s.id = sbsd.strainID AND sbd.breederID = sbsd.breederID
LEFT JOIN species AS sp ON sbsd.speciesID = sp.id
WHERE s.id = 6782
GROUP BY s.id, sbd.breederID
```

[image: Database result set]

**THE RESULT I WANT**

I would like to show a list of strain names and next to each one I would like to show a list of breeders **and the most popular/average claimed species by all breeders**. So, as I showed you earlier, the most popular species recorded by breeders for this strain is Indica/Sativa and would like this shown like this:

```
strainID  | strainName      | breeders                 | averageSpecies
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
6782      | White Widow     | Green House Seeds,       | Indica/Sativa
          |                 | Barney's Farm
```

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED:**

Instead of showing the most popular species beside each one, I have the first instance of record species next to each one. I thought this would suffice, but the first instance of a species could be empty, as currently there are about 100 strains with unknown species. So, I don't want the first instance of a species to be 'Unknown', when there are in-fact other breeders of this strain that know what species are in it. So, I'm thinking it's best to determine the most recorded species and show that instead. This is where I have got to so far:

```
SELECT
  s.id,
  s.strainName,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.breederName ORDER BY b.breederName ASC separator ', ') AS breeders,
  COALESCE(NULLIF(ps.primarySpecies,''),'Unknown') AS primarySpecies
FROM strains AS s
LEFT JOIN strainBreedersDir AS sbd ON s.id = sbd.strainID
LEFT JOIN breeders AS b ON sbd.breederID = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT
    sbd.breederID AS breederID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.species ORDER BY sp.species ASC SEPARATOR '/') AS primarySpecies
  FROM strains AS s
  LEFT JOIN strainBreedersDir AS sbd ON s.id = sbd.strainID
  LEFT JOIN strainBreederSpeciesDir AS sbsd ON s.id = sbsd.strainID AND sbd.breederID = sbsd.breederID
  LEFT JOIN species AS sp ON sbsd.speciesID = sp.id
  GROUP BY s.id, sbd.breederID
) AS ps ON sbd.breederID = ps.breederID
WHERE s.id = 6782
GROUP BY s.id
```

RESULT

```
id   | strainName   | breeders           | species
----------------------------------------------------------
6782 | White Widow  | Green House Seeds, | Indica/Sativa
     |              | Barney's Farm      |
```

But I cannot work out how to modify the `OUTER JOIN` to show the most popular species, instead of just the first joined row. I've tried so many variations of different outer join queries with many failures and have lost track of what's been tried.

How can show the most popular species?

**DATABASE STRUCTURE:**

```
strains

id (PK AUTO)     |  strainName (UNIQUE)
---------------------------------------------
6782             |  White Widow
```

--

```
strainBreedersDir

strainID (FK UNIQUE)     | breederID (UNIQUE)
---------------------------------------------
6782                     | 16
6782                     | 23
```

--

```
breeders

id (PK AUTO)      | breederName (UNIQUE)
---------------------------------------------
16                | Green House Seeds
23                | Barney's Farm
```

--

```
strainBreederSpeciesDir

strainID (FK UNIQUE)  | breederID (INT UNIQUE)  | speciesID (INT UNIQUE)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
6782                  | 16                      | 1
6782                  | 16                      | 2
6782                  | 23                      | 5
```

--

```
species

id (PK AUTO)  | species (UNIQUE)
-------------------------------------
1             | Indica
2             | Sativa
3             | Ruderalis
4             | Mostly Indica
5             | Mostly Sativa
6             | Mostly Ruderalis
```

[**HERE IS AN SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf7c6/1) - courtesy of Juan Carlos Oropeza.

Comment: Abba Zabba, you my only friend!

Comment: I will need some *sample* data to test my query.

Comment: An [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would assist us. No one likes creating tables and setting up test data so that we can test queries to ensure that they work. For you.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid  and SQLFiddle have a function on the top `Text to DDL` that will help to set up your schema.

Comment: Here is a base so you start. But probably we need more data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cd21

Comment: After long reading and without a working sample. I have a big problem because your desire output and the result you try are the same. So not sure what you need.

Comment: We need to get 420 upvotes for this question.

Comment: @Barmar  why? or you just joking?

Comment: Add `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) DESC LIMIT 1` to get the species with the most breeders.

Comment: @Alex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/420_(cannabis_culture)

Comment: @Barmar :-) thank you. I need to **see** other things not only the code sometimes :-)

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the replies and sorry for the delay. Was on a mobile device and lost contact with the world. Sorry for the lack of Fiddle - I competely forgot that. I will put one together now (hoping it's not too late).

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, the species output is the same coincidentally. It just so happened that was the first joined record. I'm trying to get the most recorded species.

Comment: i just fix a mistake in the fiddle you should use this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf7c6/1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, thanks for doing that. Very helpful.

Comment: The first one is free ;)

Comment: @Alex, there is a fiddle there now. Sorry for not having it there at the start - it slipped my mind. I feel high just developing a project about cannabis!

Comment: @PaparazzoKid your fiddle data doesn't match to the rest text of your post and examples.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: I came back just to say thanks for the 'Text to DDL' tip. Very helpful tool!

Comment: You are welcome. That function blow my mind I used to write the inserts by hand before find out. Also enjoy checking your question even when was too complicated for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going off the knowledge that you want to aggregate off of your working query.

Id probably do this a different way, but since I'm not changing your working query, this might give you what you want. The subqueries come in as the `GROUP_CONCAT` makes things a bit tougher, since we are counting on that field, and I can't stick the count straight in there (Unless someone can show me a better way) Then I choose a `MAX` or `AVG` from that. You can switch out `MAX` for `AVG`.

```
SELECT MAX(aggregated.theCount),
aggregated.id,
aggregated.breederID,
aggregated.breeders as mostPopularBreeders,
aggregated.species as mostPopularSpecies,
AllStrainBreeders.allBreeders as strainBreeders
      FROM(
    SELECT 
        speciesWithBreeder.id,
        speciesWithBreeder.breederID,
        speciesWithBreeder.breederName,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT speciesWithBreeder.breederName ORDER BY speciesWithBreeder.breederName ASC separator ', ') AS breeders,
        speciesWithBreeder.species,
        COUNT(*) as theCount
    FROM(
        SELECT
          s.id,
          b.id AS breederID,
          b.breederName AS breederName,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sp.species ORDER BY sp.species ASC SEPARATOR '/') AS species
        FROM strains AS s
        LEFT JOIN strainBreedersDir AS sbd ON s.id = sbd.strainID
        LEFT JOIN breeders AS b ON sbd.breederID = b.id
        LEFT JOIN strainBreederSpeciesDir AS sbsd ON s.id = sbsd.strainID AND sbd.breederID = sbsd.breederID
        INNER JOIN species AS sp ON sbsd.speciesID = sp.id
        WHERE s.id = 6782
        GROUP BY s.id, sbd.breederID) 
    AS speciesWithBreeder
GROUP BY speciesWithBreeder.species
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  ) as aggregated 
  LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
    sbd.strainID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.breederName ORDER BY b.breederName ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS allBreeders
    FROM breeders b  
    LEFT JOIN strainBreedersDir sbd ON sbd.breederID = b.id AND sbd.strainID = 6782
    GROUP BY sbd.strainID
   ) as AllStrainBreeders      
   ON aggregated.id = AllStrainBreeders.strainID
GROUP BY aggregated.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to make some adjustments to get it working. The results are very close, but not quite right. This is producing multiple rows for per strain, where if I took away the `where s.id = 6782`, to list all strains, I'd like one row per strain with the most popular species field populated as it is, but the breeders field needs all of the breeders names separated by commas, whether or not they have a species logged. Any suggestions? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e4fd4/5

Comment: I managed to get a little closer to my wishes by changing the group clause on the main query. I changed `GROUP BY speciesWithBreeder.species` to `GROUP BY speciesWithBreeder.id`. I now have one row per strain, as I wished, and I also have the comma delimited list of breeder names, as I wished, and I also the species. The only thing wrong now is the count field. It's not obviously not important to return the count, but I was hoping you could make sure that the count is still working okay that selects the most popular species? If it is, I'm good to go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e4fd4/9

Comment: Ok im with you now, give me a few mins.

Comment: You want `Green House Seeds, White Label // Indica/Sativa ` for white widow, then what it is for the next strain, I think?

Comment: I just confirmed that the count is wrong now after making those changes. I changed the schema by making 'Mostly Sativa' the most popular species for that strain but I still get 'Indica/Sativa': http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a19e/1

Comment: Very, very close!! For some reason, the list of breeder names is missing one record. It's missing 'Green House Seeds'? Everything else is ok, it's just that. It seems that it's returning only 3 breeder names because there is a count of 3, maybe?

Comment: Green house seeds doesnt have a 5 -> mostly sativa does it? so it shouldnt appear? you recently changed the data on that fiddle.

Comment: Getting confusing isn't it. I literally want to return the strain id, name, a comma delimited list of all breeders associated with that strain and then the most popular recorded species from those breeders. So, the `breeders` field in your working example, should contain all 4 breeders including Green House Seeds. Thanks for your time by the way - it's very kind of you.

Comment: np yes so in that, green house doesnt have a Mostly Sativa field, in the last fiddle. Should it have a presence based on it having Sativa?

Comment: Yes, the breeders field should be all breeders associated with that strain, even if the breeder doesn't have a species.

Comment: One more go, Ive tacked all the strain breeders into one column, with the original column as breeders of the most popular species.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort! That seems to have worked. I added another strain to the schema and removed the `id = 6782` parts to test and it works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a2dd/3 I can adjust things from here if needs be :)